Using the equivalent of yarn offline mirror on yarn berry
We have a setup using yarn offline mirror pointing at a create-no-modify sharepoint. The build server and half the developers use it exclusively and end up fetching all of the packages locally using essentially zero time installing packages.
The biggest winner of this is in fact the build server; trying to turn this off results in builds taking 5-10 minutes in yarn install. The normal instructions for making the cache inside the build folder don't work because the equivalent of git clean is used in the build from a context that doesn't read git configuration files inside the repo.
We have researched the modern replacement that is checking your packages into git; this doesn't work as it would make the git repo many times its current size. (literally a GB worth of packages immediately).
Some of the developers are working remotely and can't actually access the offline mirror reliably so they don't. Instructions were provided to make a local one; no idea if they used it or not.
Summary:

we are using yarn offline mirror
the mirror is create no modify for security reasons
we want to upgrade to yarn berry (latest)
we need to continue using something like yarn offline mirror
we can't store packages in the repo
the offline mirror has a few possible locations that are machine specific

How can we upgrade to latest yarn?
Running Yarn 1 is beginning to cause package resolution problems.
Yes, placing multiple yarn version tags is correct for this question.
